# How to do a File upload using selenium grid using the MacOS as a hub and WinOS as a node?

Tags: file-upload, automation, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

My Code is as below, I'm executing the script using the Mac and running 2 nodes, 1 on windows and 1 on the mac itself. The upload on the Mac works perfect but the windows upload doesnt work.

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();    
StringSelection str = new StringSelection("C:\\Sheyan.pdf");   
clipboard.setContents(str, str);
if (systemType=="http://192.168.1.100:5555/wd/hub")    **(THIS IS THE WINDOWSOS NODE)**     
{       
    Robot robot = new Robot();      
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);        
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);        
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);        
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);        
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);        
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);        
}   
else **(FOR MAC OS NODE)**
{       
    selenium.click(driver, UploadButton);       
    WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(UploadButton);        
    fileInput.sendKeys("/Users/accesstesting/Documents/Sheyan.pdf");        
}
```

Comment: Are you running scripts from MAC machine, where grid and node are running ?

Answer (score 2):

This is never going to work, the Robot commands are run on the machine that the script is running on, they are not passed over to the node.  Using the robot implementation you are using will only ever work if the tests run on the local machine.

What you want to do is use a local file detector if you are running tests against a remote node:

```
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector())
```

You would then just use your normal sendKeys() method to populate the upload input with a local file and Selenium will perform some magic in the background to pass any files through the grid so that they can be uploaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try this and works on the remote node. 

However, the file gets uploaded but the popup window doesnt get closed. When i manually close the window, the file has been uploaded.

Comment: You shouldn't click on the button at all, let the send keys deal with it for you.  Once you click on the button you are in OS dialogue territory which Selenium can't deal with.

Comment: The sendkeys alone didnt work. However, without the click I used verfiyElementExist and it works well along with the sendkeys. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is more like question than an answer, but still: Why do you use Robot on Windows node and Selenium on Mac node?

What happens if you do this?

```
 if (systemType=="http://192.168.1.100:5555/wd/hub")    **(THIS IS THE WINDOWSOS NODE)** 
 {       
  selenium.click(driver, UploadButton);       
  WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(UploadButton);        
  fileInput.sendKeys("C:\\Sheyan.pdf");        
}
```

Because if selenium and driver are correctly initialised on the Windows node, this should work

Comment: I Did try this, however i guess the sendKeys doenst work. The file upload pop up remains empty.

Comment: my general idea is use rather Selenium code and not the Robot as you are doing right now. Try to investigate on the sendkeys, but it will be rather issue in your code than in selenium itself...